# Pandas read_excel AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

Tags: python, pandas

I am receiving an error using the read_excel command from pandas. I am trying to import an .xls file, but I get this error. It happens when I try the ExcelFile command as well. Funny thing, I do not receive the error on a virtual machine running the same code. Is it the way pandas was installed?

The error is on my desktop Python 3.6 version, my virtual machine runs 3.7

Error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\SHARED\Accounts Receivable\First Payment Defaults\Build\First Payment Defaults.py", line 27, in <module>
    headers = pd.ExcelFile(r"\\sfcfile-2\DataModule\IL\leasing.contract.extract.new headers.xlsx")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 141, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 265, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 392, in do_sheet
    sheet = Sheet(bk, position=None, name=name, number=sheetx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.extract_formulas = book.extract_formulas
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'
```

Comment: looks like a problem with the `xlrd` module, compare the versions between your machine where it works and where it doesn't, you may need to upgrade

Comment: you can run `import xlrd`, `print(xlrd.__version__)`